# Publishing container port range as the same range on the host at docker runtime

Tags: docker

Given the following `Dockerfile` configuration

```
EXPOSE 9400-9500
```

I would like to achieve the same effect in `docker run` as `--publish-all=true`, but with the resulting mapping being to a given port range rather than random, e.g. `0.0.0.0:8301->9400/tcp ... 0.0.0.0:8401->9500/tcp`, sequentially. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have just found the answer:

```
docker run -p 8301-8401:9400-9500 ...
```